# How to scale (jQuery)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'd like to create a `scale animation` on an element using jQuery animations.

So there is a element given with the **property** `transform: "scale(0.5)"` and I'd like to animate this scaleFactor of `"scale(0.5)"` to another specific value like e.g `"scale(1.2)"` or `"scale(0.3)"`.

**How can I achieve this?**

**Note**: *I'd like to use just* **jQuery**, *no CSS transition styles, etc*

**Note**: This is the code I got so far. Obviously it is not working this way to animate a scale like `1.4` to another scale like `0.5` and the second problem is that the animations just runs one time.

```js
$("input").click(function() {
  $(".elem").css({
    transform: 'scale(1)'
  }).animate({
    new_scale: 1.2
  }, {
    step: function(value) {
      $(".elem").css({
        transform: 'scale(' + value + ')'
      });
    },
    duration: 1000
  });

})
```

```css
.elem {
  background: red;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="elem"></div>
<input type="button" value="animation" style="margin-top: 10px" />
```

*So any help how to fix this or even some better solutions would be very appreciated. Thanks a million In advance!*

Comment: Have you considered a pure CSS solution with no jQuery at all?

Comment: No I'd like to get use a pure jQuery solution. No Css-style using at all! @Bonnie :)

Comment: @jonas00 `transform: scale` *is* CSS, so you're stuffed there.

Comment: Yeah, I would recommend using a combination of vanilla JS and CSS3 transitions. If you're loading jQuery for something else, you might as well use it, but I wouldn't load an entire library just to do one animation.

Comment: I'm using jQuery for a lot of stuff, so this is working fine with loading the library. But I have to make need of the jQuery animations right there. However.

Comment: If this is a learning exercise then knock yourself out, but if this is for a production environment then I'd strongly suggest that you use CSS, as it's better suited to the task, not to mention performs *much* better than JS animation.

Answer (score 1):

No jQuery required.

Just use CSS `transition: transform;`

```js
document.getElementById('clickme').onclick = function() {
  var target = Math.random()+0.5; // for testing, give a random value between 0.5 and 1.5
  document.getElementById('elem').style.transform = "scale("+target+")";
};
```

```css
#elem {
  background: red;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  transition: transform 1s linear;
}
```

```html
<div id="elem"></div>
<input type="button" id="clickme" value="animation" style="margin-top: 10px" />
```